# Truncated text from Query in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

When I perform the query in mysql terminal, it works fine. The data in the database is not truncated. Its only when I query in sqlalchemy python that I get this truncation error:
(38810 characters truncated)

Here is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE `papers` (
  `pid` int NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `extracted_text` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `keywords` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `summary` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `extracted_references` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Here is my code.

```
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import select

engine = db.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:123456@localhost/research')
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = db.MetaData()
papers = db.Table('papers', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)


result = engine.execute('SELECT * FROM papers')
for record in result:
    print(record)
```

Result:
(3, 'extremesum', ' Findings  Association for Computational Li ... (38810 characters truncated) ... Accelerator award 1936940,', 'tldr,paper,abstracts,multiple gold summaries,scitldr,see appendix table,models,scientific papers,catts,auth', 'In addition to establishing strong extractive and abstractive summarization baselines using Transformer-based (Vaswani et al., 2017) models, we prese ... (394 characters truncated) ... n order to write high-quality gold TLDRs. , Yu Wang, Songhao Piao, Jianfeng Gao, Ming Zhou, and Hsiao-Wuen Hon.\n2020. Unilmv2: ... (9760 characters truncated) ... n. In\nACL.\nMing Zhong, Pengfei Liu, Yiran Chen, Danqin')

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You're printing the record's `__repr__`, which may well truncate long strings.   Try print(record.extracted_text)` (or whatever is the name of the truncated field) .

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks you were right.